# How many numbers can be written as a sum?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> How many integers can be written as a sum of 4 consecutive integers such that the numbers are < $2015$.

**EDITED QUESTION:**

> If $N = n + (n + 1) + (n+ 2) + (n + 3)$ then how many such $N$ exist such that $0 < N < 2015$ as well as $n \ge 0$?

*The source was flawed, the actual question is the one above.

Obviously,

$n + n +1 + n +2 + n + 3 = 4n + 6 < 2015 \implies 4n < 2009 \implies n \le 502$.

The first number $N$ must be $N = 6$, and the last: $502 + 503 + 504 + 505 = 2014$.

Hence there are: $n \in [0, 502] \implies 503$ values for $n$?

Comment: "Such that the numbers are $< 2015$" is ambiguous: do you mean that the numbers (plural) going into the sum are $< 2015$, or that the sum (singular) of them is $< 2015$, as you seem to have interpreted?  Also, there are infinitely many integers less than $2015$: nowhere did you restrict this to positive integers.

Comment: You need to be somewhat more precise in your wording of the problem.  By "integers" do you mean "positive integers" or "non-negative integers"? (Also, the reference to numbers that are less than $2015$ leaves it unclear whether you mean the sums or the numbers being summed.)

Comment: @ErickWong, interesting we posted essentially the same comment almost simultaneously.

Comment: @BarryCipra My upvote was enthusiastic on account of the synchronicity :).

Comment: @ErickWong, word for word copy from another source. I think the sum of all 4 has to be $< 2015$

Comment: @Amad27 That means the source is flawed.  The question is in your hands: what do you *want* it to mean?  If you don't know what it is you're asking, then this isn't really a question and should be closed.

Comment: @ErickWong, Okay. Let it mean this. If $N = n + (n + 1) + (n+ 2) + (n + 3)$ then how many such $N$ exist such that $0 < N < 2015$ as well as $n \ge 0$? Is  my answer correct then?

Comment: @Amad27 Thanks. Your analysis looks perfectly correct.

Comment: @ErickWong. Dammit, it was marked as wrong!! Perhaps the source meant something else then...